# T-SQL query that can sum up expenses for the current month, what that sumed average is for all months

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions, average

I have a table with `Month_Id(int), Year(nvarchar), Expenses(money)`.

I need a report that shows the sum of a current month, and what the average of that month would be.

This is what I got so far.

```
SELECT     dt.Date, dt.Other_Revenue, dt.Month_Id, dt.Date_Year
FROM         S1_Rpt_Daily_Totals 
WHERE     (dt.Month_Id = MONTH(GETDATE()))
```

Logic -  To add up the sum of expenses in Sept 2012, 2011, 2010, ect and divide by the number of years to get my Average.

BUT how do I do this in a SQL query. Is it possible?

Disclaimer - I am pretty new at SQL.

Comment: Your table def doesn't match your query.

Comment: Correction Table - Month_Id(int), Date_Year(nvarchar), Revenue(money). Date  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Is there only one year's worth of data in your table?  If not, you'll need to add the year to your where clause

Comment: Year is being used as a way to goup the data. I dont think it has to be a date. But I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Hi Beth, There is 5 years of Data. So I Need to Sum Up my Septembers and then divde by the number of years , can this be held in some kind of variable in Sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL Server 2005+ you should be able to use this:

```
;with a(sumexpenses, [month])
as
(
select  SUM(Expenses)
        ,DATEADD(month, datediff(month,0,[Date]), 0)
from    S1_Rpt_Daily_Totals
group by 
        DATEADD(month, datediff(month,0,[Date]), 0)
)

select  a1.[month]
        ,a1.sumexpenses
        ,AVG(a2.sumexpenses) as average
from    a a1
join    a a2
    on  MONTH(a1.[month]) = MONTH(a2.[month])
group by 
        a1.[month]
        ,a1.sumexpenses
```

This solution only uses the Date, so if it works you might get rid of month_id and date_year.

Comment: Thanks Johan.  I think this might do it. At least logically this is what I was looking for. This Message board rocks.

Comment: Update -Worked, This is exactly what i was looking for. Brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MONTH(Date), sum(Expenses), avg(Expenses)
FROM S1_Rpt_Daily_Totals
GROUP BY MONTH(Date);
```

But I'm not sure what is definition of your table - I only guessed from given SQL.

Comment: Ok I tried it. Didnt get the results. Ill post the definition of the table. I appreciate you trying. I think if I give you more information youll be able to help me.

Comment: id(int), Date(date), Expenses(Money), Date_Year(nvarchar), Month_id(int)  Example: I need to know what My average of Expenses are for this month,  by summing up sept in the past and dividing by the number of years.

Comment: If you already have the date, why would you need month_id and date_year?